# ImageView Transition Animation after loading

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I want to load a ImageView and then fade it in. But for now it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

> ```
>         getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>             @Override
>             public void run() {
>                 // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.
>                 ProgressBar pb_befree = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pb_befree);
>                 ImageView befree = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.befree);
>                 befree.setImageResource(R.drawable.sc_befreejpg);
>                 pb_befree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
> ```

```
                Animation animFade;
                animFade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.motivation_fadein);
                befree.setAnimation(animFade);

                befree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="100"
        android:duration="500"/>

</set>
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I get no Exception or something. The animation is just missing.

Comment: befree.startAnimation(...)

Comment: No Change with startAnimation tried it before and after the setVisibility.

Comment: The Square Picasso library loads images in an imageviewn and fades them in by default. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
                    animation1.setDuration(1000);
                    animation1.setStartOffset(100);
                    animation1.setFillAfter(true);
                    befree.startAnimation(animation1);

Answer (score 0):

just remove the alpha from the imageview properties & it will work :)

if you are setting it in the layout like this

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/befree"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/artwork"/>
```

Comment: You mean befree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);? If i remove it nothing shows up after loading. Should i mention that i am in a Fragment,in a AsyncTask and from there in a Runnable? Is it important?

Comment: no not befree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
can you post your layout the part of the ImageView